# JSlider Label is not completely visible (java)

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jslider

I have made a player that can display few steps with different images.

Under this player I have added a JSlider, to jump to every step. It should have labels for the first and last steps.

I managed by setting my own LabelTable for the JSlider.

It works very well for numbers under 100. But numbers with three or more digits get are cut off.

See the bottom-right corner of this image. Step 438 is not completely visible:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Eyb.png]

Is it possible to get the last (step)label completely visible?

I have already tried:

- set the (max, min, preferred) size of the slider
- get the JLabel over getLabelTable and set the location (a few pixels to the left) of the JLabel, but it is always (0,0).

The JSlider uses the SynthSliderUI.

Thank you! ;)

Comment: Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem. So first start with a simple JFrame that only contains the slider with values from 1 - 438. If it works great, then you know the problem is with the  layout of other components. So you add one component at a time to see when it starts to break. If it doesn't work then you have simple code of 10-20 lines to post in the forum that we can test to see if we have the same problem.